# I am running into errors installing a requirements.txt. The issue I am having is with pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am relatively new to the world of coding and am mostly self taught. Currently I am working on a project via a repository from GitHub. One of the steps in working with the code is to install python dependencies via a requirements.txt

I am currently running into errors with pillow. I am working in windows, and currently have python 3.9.7 and conda 4.13.0. When I run the python -m pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt i get errors as follows:

```
1) Building wheels for collected packages: pillow
  Building wheel for pillow (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [189 lines of output]
      C:\Users\kj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hsdc08bl\pillow_07ce73d2c2484297acb81cb082ed4b48\setup.py:29: RuntimeWarning: Pillow does not yet support Python 3.9 and does not yet provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.

2)  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\kj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hsdc08bl\pillow_07ce73d2c2484297acb81cb082ed4b48\setup.py", line 888, in <module>
          raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
      __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow

3)  Running setup.py clean for pillow
Failed to build pillow
Installing collected packages: pillow, h5py, pandas, matplotlib, sklearn, scikit-image
  Attempting uninstall: pillow
 Found existing installation: Pillow 9.1.1
    Uninstalling Pillow-9.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled Pillow-9.1.1
  Running setup.py install for pillow ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pillow did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [193 lines of output]
      C:\Users\kj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hsdc08bl\pillow_07ce73d2c2484297acb81cb082ed4b48\setup.py:29: RuntimeWarning: Pillow does not yet support Python 3.9 and does not yet provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.

4)  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  WARNING: No metadata found in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
  Rolling back uninstall of pillow
  Moving to c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pil\
   from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\~il
  Moving to c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pillow-9.1.1.dist-info\
   from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\~illow-9.1.1.dist-info
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pillow

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

These are all the errors I get when I run the install of requirements.txt. I have done some research on my own before looking for help as there are similar questions I have come across. One issue is that pillow does not yet support python 3.9. However, on pillows readthedoc it claims that python 3.9 is supported by pillow >=9.0, and I have pillow 9.1.1 installed. Another issue I see is the headers or library files could not be found for zlib, yet I have used conda install -c anaconda zlib.
```

To reiterate, I am relatively still a beginner with code. I would appreciate any friendly advice with my current issues.

Thank you

Comment: It doesn't seem to be able to build Pillow for Python 3.9 AFAIK. I guess you'll need to go to an older Python - or maybe if there is some version number after Pillow in your `requirements.txt` you could delete that and the equals sign and  try again and see if it can find something else compatible.

Answer (score 0):

When installing this library, pip tried to find a pre-compiled binary (`bdist_wheel`) but couldn't find one that matches your python version and OS. So it tried to build it from source, but you don't have `zlib` installed on your machine. [`zlib`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is another program that is used in the python build process. You can install it for windows from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zlib.htm), or I think it is bundled with Python if you install Python using the "Full Installer" as described here: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html